# Trying to use 'xdotool' in a bin/bash shell - help?

Tags: bash, scripts, xdotool

We have a '.sh' file that opens chromium browser, then opens an application via an 'http' address, then waits at a login screen for user input (clicking on button) to sign in.  I am trying to use `xdotool` to execute (3) tab key's & (1) spacebar key, or enter key, to "click" the sign in button.

I am new to bash, `xdotool` and Ubuntu in general. Maybe `xdotool` is not the right method? Any tips would be appreciated.

See below the existing '.sh' file, this command line works:

```
#!/bin/bash
(sleep 45 && chromium-browser --kiosk http://127.0.0.1:8080) &
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
xdotool key Tab Tab Tab Return
```

or:

```
xdotool key Tab Tab Tab space
```

Comment: This answer doesn't tell, 1-how to wait for chromium to open and 2- how to focus? before sending tab tab return commands

Comment: @Hernán That wasn't part of the question. If you want to know, you could ask a new question. But FWIW, to wait for Chromium, I would just try putting in a `sleep 5` and hoping for the best. To focus, it depends on the window manager. I know you can set the default Gnome setup so that new windows always take focus.